# Firebase rules in an online store without users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am just starting in firebase with databases and I have a problem, I am making a page about an online store where I do not want there to be any kind of authentication, I just want the products to be seen with a brief description, but the problem is  that every day a firebase email arrives telling me that my rules are insecure, so I wanted to know how to set my rules so that they are safe and only the information is displayed on my own page.

These are the rules I currently use:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
            allow write: if false; allow read: if true;
        }
     }
}
```

I understand that they are open to all people, my idea is that at the moment it does not save any type of sensitive information in my database, I just want to save product data about my store, such as the price or a description avoiding all sensitive information.  , my object is to return the safe rules and to be able to see the data from my page without any type of authentication for it.

Comment: There realy is not enough information here to know what exactly you need.  You will have to translate your security requirements into rules that limit user access in a way that you see fit.  Good rules are never a matter of just copying in the correct lines - you will have to understand how the rules system works and implement the rules for your needs.  I suggest you start reading here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: @DougStevenson - What is unclear about this question? The OP presumably has a single collection for which they want allow unauthenticated reads and no writes.  Should the rules in this post generate a warning?  I think the correct answer is that the OP can fix this by spelling out the collection path explicitly in the second `match` statement, but I defer to your depth of knowledge to be certain.

Comment: @danh "presumably" is the key word here.  We need to be able to know **exactly** which collections are in play here, and how the user is expected to be able to interact with each of them.  And, without Firebase Auth in play, full read and write access is still not really "secure" at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll wager that google would consider the rules sufficiently locked down if the specific collection path was spelled out....

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /Put_Your_Product_Collection_Path_Here/{productDoc=**} {
            allow write: if false; allow read: if true;
        }
     }
}
```

If you have other collections, be sure to secure those, too.

Comment: It's worth noting that allowing full read and write access, even with a named collection, is not "secure", and definitely not advisable if it can be avoided.  As shown now, one can expect a massive bill for data written by anyone with an internet connection, and also total data loss.  (also you are missing a wildcard on the collection match)

Comment: Ok thanks, I am going to test these rules all day and I will see if I get any Google security problem, I am aware that the rules are insecure but at least in the type of project I am doing I do not see much sense in putting  rules to something that anyway users are going to see in some way or another in that specific database

Comment: @DougStevenson - edited to add wildcard and to advise doing this for all collections.  I think you're mistaken to characterize this as  "full read and write access".  How are you reading this as "full write" access, vulnerable to a massive bill?   Is `allow write: if false;` insufficient somehow?

Comment: It's confusing because you have two allow statements on a single line.  It's conventional for each allow to start a new line, for readability.

Comment: Anyway, @hackerpro, to recap: you need to specifically name the collection being defended.